Cannot log in to Xubuntu 24.04 LTS after install
After installing Xubuntu 24.04 and defining my password, I reboot to log in for the first time.
My password is rejected and it is the good one. I install again in vain.
After looking to this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNc2Dwz6vNw, I was able to reset the password to the same and it works.

Issues such as lack of available space in $HOME can prevent a GUI login, but terminal login will still occur. Your question confuses me though (it is the good one?  what checks did you do to ensure you typed it correctly?  Did you explore the system password for an expected hash or how?), and I was able to install 24.04 and have no-password entry in /etc/passwd  and /etc/shadow in QA which your question maybe fits (I doubt it though), but your question is too vague as it covers many possible (mostly user-created) issues.

I tried 3 times the whole installation process and I carefully typed each letter in my password. After I changed the password with exactly the same password, I had no more issues to log in.

@stumblebee. I sourced my information in order to match with the forum guidelines. This may be for someone who tries to understand the issue but also for noobs like to who face the same issue and may get some help. I understand I failed to closely match these guidelines. I will reconsider posting additional issues in the future.

I had the same problem today. My case:
I have a QWERTZ Keyboard and had to type the password as if written in QWERTY Layout. That was it for me.

No it was not a keyboard issue since I always check for the French appropriate setting when I install.

Detailed steps:

Restart pressing SHIFT (in my case) to access GNU GRUB
Select Advanced options for Ubuntu
Select Ubuntu...(recovery mode)
In the recovery menu select root then press ENTER
In the shell below, enter mount -o remount, rw /
Enter passwd your_login
Enter your password twice.
Enter exit to leave the shell
Select resume to boot.


Alternative to 5. run the fsck option in the menu before 4. i.e. as "step 3.5".
